# Ending checkbox text with semicolon

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

This could have been asked before but I cannot find it so apologies if it has.

I have a windows forms app (VS2017 C#) with a requirement to add a semi colon to the end of each label.  When I add the text to a checkbox the semi colon appears at the beginning of the text (the tick box should follow after the text so the LeftToRight property is set to yes):

Text added to label = `"Show On Web: "`

The text displays as `" :Show On Web"`

If I use:

Text added to label =  `" :Show On Web"`

The text displays as `"Show On Web: "`

This image show what gets displayed and the properties set at design time.

[image]

Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: Checkboxes are normally before their label (so they line up vertically), which puts the semi-colon between the box and text.

Comment: I think you want to change the `CheckAlign` property instead of the `RightToLeft` property. That will effectively swap the positions of the Checkbox and the Label

Comment: @Mikev  there is no code this is from design with no code added.

Comment: Neither a [semicolon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon) (`;`) nor a [colon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)) (`:`) belongs into a checkbox label.

Comment: @JayV lol I knew it would be something like that!  Spot on!

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.RightToLeft);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) tells us that "The RightToLeft property is used for international applications where the **language is written from right to left**, such as Hebrew or Arabic."

Comment: I guess it assumes that non alphanumeric characters **at the end of the string** belong at the end of a text, which is on the left side when you write from right to left

Comment: @UweKeim  I agree, hence I have never come across this before. Sometime a developer doesn't get a say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation tells us about [RightToLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.RightToLeft);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) the following:

> The RightToLeft property is used for international applications where the **language is written from right to left**, such as Hebrew or Arabic. When this property is set to RightToLeft.Yes, control elements that include text are displayed from right to left.

It preserves the order of letters and numbers, but apparently all non-alphanumeric at the end of the string will end up at the most left side, which would be the end of a line when you read from right to left.

Example:

```
checkBox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
checkBox1.Text = "first second, third 1 2 3 = <";
```

Result:

[image]

So to answer your question:

> Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something?

is *yes*.

I guess you actually would like to use the [CheckAlign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkalign?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.CheckAlign);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) property:

```
checkBox1.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
checkBox1.Text = "first second, third 1 2 3 = <";
```

Result:

[image]